# Is there a way to programmatically update frames (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frames

Is it possible to update the frames like in the interface builder but programmatically? Some of my objects get misplaced because of an animation (which I'll want to fix anyway, I guess..) but it brought to mind the aforementioned question

Edit: I have done some googling as well as looking on stackoverflow and not found what I'm looking for.
I want to update the frames of some buttons back to the constraints I set in the interface builder.
Sorry if this is too simple of a question, but I'm just looking for a simple answer: yes or no + line of code or the method to call. it probably won't even end up in my final project; I'm just curious.

Here's some code, since I guess that would help:

```
@IBAction func optionsButtonPushed(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
        var theFrame = self.optionsMenu.frame
        theFrame.size.height += 100
        self.optionsMenu.frame  = theFrame
    })
}
```

The buttons located in the view I'm rolling in (from a height of zero) disappear because of the animation, I guess, so there's probably a better way than what I'm thinking
(sorry this question is so crazy; it's my first one!)

Comment: Rachel, this is a bad question for StackOverflow. You have not demonstrated what you have tried, what has not worked, what research you have made.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Your question needs more detail... what kind of frames?  UIView frames?  or Game/Scene Kit frames, or?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable auto-layout. from storyboard. IF you still want to use AutoLayout then use `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

```
self.yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

self.yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(16, 133, 130, 130);
```

Comment: yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true is what I was looking for after initially setting it to false

Answer (score 2):

`UIView` has a property called `frame` which is of type `CGRect`. `CGRect` is a struct.

You can update it by creating a new `CGRect` and assigning it to the property.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100)
yourView.frame = newFrame
```

[UIView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame)

Comment: Use CGRectMake(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100) not CGRect()

Comment: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100) is fine. This initialiser is defined in the CGRect extension.