# Swift: Changing UIView frame but display doesn't update

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, frame

I'm trying to dynamically resize the frame of a UIView.  I can update the frame in the code and see that the values have changed, but the actual display never changes, even though I run setNeedsDisplay().

I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057862/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-update-frames-swift), where I define a new frame via CGRectMake, and then set the UIView's frame to this new frame.  i.e., I'm doing this...

```
let newFrame = CGRectMake(minX,minY, width, height)
VUBarCover.frame = newFrame
```

If I print out the value of the UIView's frame, I see that it's changing as I like.  But the display (in the Simulator) never reflects these changes.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update:** In greater detail: I'm trying to programmatically cover up one UIView with another.  It's a horizontal "VU Meter", consisting of a base UIImageView showing a color gradient, that gets partially dynamically "covered" up by a UIView with a black background.
The UIImageView "VUBarImageView" is defined in StoryBoard and is subject to AutoLayout.  The black UIView "VUBarCover" is defined purely programmatically, with no AutoLayout constraints.

Here's the relevant parts of the code for completeness... The trouble I'm having is in updateVUMeter()...

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var VUBarImageView: UIImageView!
var VUBarCover : UIView!

// this gets called after AutoLayout is finished
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        // cover up VU Meter completely
        let center = VUBarImageView.center
        let width = VUBarImageView.frame.width
        let height = VUBarImageView.frame.height
        let frame = VUBarImageView.frame
        VUBarCover = UIView(frame: frame)
        MainView.addSubview(VUBarCover)
        VUBarCover.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() // use black eventually. blue lets us see it for testing
    }

 // partially cover up VUBarImage with black VUBarCover coming from the "right"
func updateVUMeter(inputValue:Float) {   //inputValue is in dB

    //let val = pow(10.0,inputValue/10)  // convert from dB
    let val = Float( Double(arc4random())/Double(UInt32.max) ) //for Simulator testing, just use random numbers between 0 and 1
    print("val = ",val)

    let fullWidth = VUBarImageView.frame.width
    let maxX = VUBarImageView.frame.maxX
    let width = fullWidth * CGFloat(1.0-val)
    let minX = maxX - width
    let minY = VUBarImageView.frame.minY
    let height = VUBarImageView.frame.height

    let newFrame = CGRectMake(minX,minY, width, height)
    VUBarCover.frame = newFrame
    VUBarCover.setNeedsDisplay()

    print("fullWidth = ",fullWidth,"width = ",width)
    print(" newFrame = ",newFrame,"VUBarCover.frame = ",VUBarCover.frame)
}
```

And sample results are:

```
val =  0.9177
fullWidth =  285.0 width =  23.4556210041046
newFrame =  (278.544378995895, 93.5, 23.4556210041046, 10.0) VUBarCover.frame =  (278.544378995895, 93.5, 23.4556210041046, 10.0)
val =  0.878985
fullWidth =  285.0 width =  34.4891595840454
newFrame =  (267.510840415955, 93.5, 34.4891595840454, 10.0) VUBarCover.frame =  (267.510840415955, 93.5, 34.4891595840454, 10.0)
val =  0.955011
fullWidth =  285.0 width =  12.8218790888786
newFrame =  (289.178120911121, 93.5, 12.8218790888786, 10.0) VUBarCover.frame =  (289.178120911121, 93.5, 12.8218790888786, 10.0)
```

...i.e., we see that VUBarCover.frame is changing 'internally', but on the screen it never changes.  What we see instead is the full-size cover, completely covering the image below (ca. 300 pixels wide), even though its width should be only, about 12 pixels).

Even if I do a setNeedsDisplay() on the superview of VUBarCover, nothing changes.

Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have a few errors worth noting:

- Instance variables (like `VUBarCover` and `MainView` should always begin with a lowercase letter (like `mainView`).
- You should call `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` at the beginning of your override implementation

Second, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can be called any number of times, so your implementation of this method should be *idempotent*, meaning it has an identical effect no matter how many times it's called. But when you call:

```
VUBarCover = UIView(frame: frame)
MainView.addSubview(VUBarCover)
```

You are creating a *new* `UIView` and adding it to the view hierarchy, along with the others you may have added in the past. So it *looks* like the frame isn't updating on the screen. In fact, you just can't tell because the *old* views are behind the one you're updating and *they're* not changing.

Instead, you probably want to create this once:

```
var vuBarCover = UIView()
```

Add it as a subview in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
mainView.addSubview(vuBarCover)
```

And modify its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
vuBarCover.frame = vuBarImageView.frame
```

You don't need to call `setNeedsDisplay()`.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your detailed answer.   Ignoring my stylistic choice of beginning capitals for global variables, I've implemented what you described and the difference is that now, the VUBarCover appears on the display as having zero width, i.e. it doesn't cover the image at all, and otherwise the same issues apply: 'internally' I can see the frame changing via print statements, but on the display nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps it's getting cropped by another view? Have you tried using the new-ish [Debug View Hierarchy](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) feature? The only other thing I can think of is that maybe you're calling `updateVUMeter` from a background thread instead of the main thread

Comment: Background thread was my assumption.  @sh37211, what code is calling updateVUMeter?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, **there were animations left on the layer**, after removing them, the frame changes are updated:

```
myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

iOS displays `presentationLayer` of a `UIView` on the screen, animations are played on that layer (`frame` updates goes there during animation).

Answer (score 1):

I am making a custom UIView like you right now, maybe I can help.

Firstly, **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** like your comment:  this gets called after AutoLayout is finished. And after every layout did set, you start to set new frame for your UIView and UIImage, maybe the bug is here. Please try to move your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews() to **layoutSubviews()**. And don't forget add super.layoutSubviews() in override function, which can help you away from hundreds of bugs :].

Secondly, only if you override the **drawRect:** method, then you should call **setNeedsDisplay()**, which is telling system that i need to redraw my view, and system will call drawRect: method appropriately.

Hope you can figure it out.